# Http Request "Get"

Tags: java, android

I have a Class, what send a Http Request to a Server.
In this class i create a timestamp. The variable for hour, minute... is correct and fill with the correct variable. But when i create my timestamp variable it gives an exeption, but the massage come not in the log cat and i dont know why.

My Code:

```
    public String GetData(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {

        String tag [] = {"Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"};
        String monat [] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime( new Date() );

        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int hourOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        String timestamp = tag[dayOfWeek] + ", " + dayOfMonth + " " + monat[month] + " " + year + " " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + "GMT";

        String timeAndAppID = HttpHandler.LoginParams.appid + timestamp;

        String hash = getMD5EncryptedString(timeAndAppID);

        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        conn.setRequestProperty("WWSVC-TS", timestamp);
        conn.setRequestProperty("WWSVC-HASH", hash);

        conn.connect();

        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Show your exception

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for date formatting? Looks like you are doing a lot unnecessary manually.

Comment: Yes i take a look before :/

Comment: You were already asked to post the exception. Please do.

Comment: `Calendar` implicitly applies your JVM’s current default time zone. So your report of the timestamp as GMT (UTC) is wrong, incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
              .format( DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME )
```

> Tue, 3 Jun 2008 11:05:30 GMT

## Details

We cannot solve your exact problem as you have not yet provided the Exception information after being asked twice for it.

I can shorten, and correct, your date-time code. The code in the Question misreports a date-time as being GMT/UTC when in fact it is in the JVM’s current default time zone that is implicitly applied by the `GregorianCalendar` class.

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

To get the current moment in UTC (GMT), simply ask for an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

For communicating date-time values between systems, you should be using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The java.time classes use these standard formats when generating and parsing strings.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2017-03-26T00:25:07.521Z

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2017-03-26T00:25:07.521Z" );
```

If you insist on using your particular format instead, let `DateTimeFormatter` class do the work of generating the string. No need to specify a formatting pattern, as your format appears to that defined by RFC 1123 / RFC 822. That formatter is already [pre-defined in java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME). But note that your code does not abbreviate the month names in the same manner as the RFC.

Lastly, I will repeat myself: This is a *terrible* format as it is difficult to read, difficult to parse, and assumes English language – I urge you to use ISO 8601 formats instead. Modern protocols and standards have abandoned these old RFCs’ format to use ISO 8601 instead.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ;
```

The `Instant` class a basic building block class in java.time. For more features such as formatting, convert to an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object using the [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) constant.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
String output = odt.format( f );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).